# inheritance of exception classes in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm writing some exception classes in c++ that inherit from a base class and I can't figure out why it won't compile. Any help would be appreciated.

`Base Class: 
RandomAccessFileException.h`

```
#ifndef RANDOMACCESSFILEEXCEPTION_H
#define RANDOMACCESSFILEEXCEPTION_H

class RandomAcessFileException
{
public:
    RandomAcessFileException();
    virtual const char* getMessage() = 0;
protected:
    char m_message[100];
};

#endif
```

`Derived Class:
RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.h`

```
#ifndef RANDOMACCESSFILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION_H
#define RANDOMACCESSFILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION_H

#include "RandomAccessFileException.h"

class RandomAccessFileNotFoundException : public RandomAccessFileException
{
public:
    RandomAccessFileNotFoundException(const char* p_filename);
    const char* getMessage();
};

#endif
```

`RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.cpp`

```
#include <cstring>

#include "RandomAccessFileException.h"
#include "RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.h"

RandomAccessFileNotFoundException::RandomAccessFileNotFoundException(const char* p_filename)
{
    strcat(m_message, "RandomAccessFileNotFoundException: File: ");
    strcat(m_message, p_filename);
}

const char* RandomAccessFileNotFoundException::getMessage()
{
    return m_message;
}
```

g++ says:

In file included from RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.cpp:4:0:
RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.h:13:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.cpp: In constructor ‘RandomAccessFileNotFoundException::RandomAccessFileNotFoundException(const char*)’:
RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.cpp:8:12: error: ‘m_message’ was not declared in this scope
RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.cpp: In member function ‘const char*    RandomAccessFileNotFoundException::getMessage()’:
RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.cpp:14:12: error: ‘m_message’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Also, to make your life simpler, I'd suggest deriving all of your exceptions from `std::exception` so that "catch-all" and such is much simpler for you later when you're catching via base class.  Include `<exception>` to get the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem:**

You have to:

```
#include "RandomAccessFileException.h"
```

In your `RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.h` header file, since it contains the definition of the base class of `RandomAccessFileNotFoundException` (i.e. `RandomAccessFileException`).

So to sum it up, your header file `RandomAccessFileNotFoundException.h` header should be:

```
#ifndef RANDOMACCESSFILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION_H
#define RANDOMACCESSFILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION_H

#include "RandomAccessFileException.h"

class RandomAccessFileNotFoundException : public RandomAccessFileException
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                               This class is defined in the
//                                               RandomAccessFileException.h
//                                               header, so you have to #include
//                                               that header before using this
//                                               class as a base class.
{
public:
    RandomAccessFileNotFoundException(const char* p_filename);
    const char* getMessage();
};

#endif
```

**Second problem:**

Also notice that you have a typo. Your base class is called:

```
RandomAcessFileException
//     ^
```

Instead of:

```
RandomAccessFileException
//     ^^
```

Which is the name you are using in `RandomAccessFileException.h`.

**Third problem:**

Finally, you are missing a *definition* of the base class's (`RandomAccessFile`) constructor, for which you have provided just a *declaration*:

```
class RandomAcessFileException
{
public:
    RandomAcessFileException();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  This is a DECLARATION of the constructor, but the definition is missing
    virtual const char* getMessage() = 0;
protected:
    char m_message[100];
};
```

Without providing a definition, the linker will emit an unresolved reference error.

Comment: @user2325753: I updated the answer. You have a typo in the name of the base class